# Magento Change Order Status from REST API

Tags: c#, api, rest, magento, magento-1.9

I am 'communicating' with a Magento web app(version 1.9.2.2) via the REST API in a C# ASP.NET MVC application.

The application essentially acts as a backend order flow dashboard for pizzas. I need to display the latest orders and allow the user to check the items off as they are processed (among other things).

I am able to retrieve orders, products, customers etc; but need to be able to update the order status. From my research it seems that this can be achieved by adding an order comment.

**That said, my questions are as follows:**

1. Is adding an order comment (thus updating the order status) only possible through the SOAP Service in Magento 1.9?
2. If the above is true, how can I update the order status of a particular order using another *secure* approach?

Docs on REST API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/order_comments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone that may be facing the same issue, I discovered that it is not possible to update the order status (AKA add a sales order comment) via the REST API. You have to use the SOAP API and version 2 makes it easiest.

**Setup:**

1. In magento, create a SOAP Role and User
2. Add the SOAP v2 API as a web reference to your Visual Studio project

**Code:**

```
public void UpdateOrderStatus(string orderIncrementId, string newStatus, string comment = "")
{
    // Init service with uri
    var service = new MagentoSoap.MagentoService();
    // Login - username and password (soap api key) of the soap user
    string sessionId = service.login(Username, Password);
    // Update order status
    service.salesOrderAddComment(sessionId, orderIncrementId, newStatus, comment, 1, true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the addComment method, which also lets you specify the new order status as one of it's parameters.

```
$sku='100000003';
$orderStatus = 'Downloaded';
$comment = 'The order was successfully downloaded';
$sendEmailToCustomer = false;

$proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.addComment', array($sku, $orderStatus, $comment, $sendEmailToCustomer));
```